# Adding multiple nodes and relationships in one transaction using neo4jclient

Tags: c#, neo4jclient

I am new to neo4j and neo4jclient so please excuse if my question is not on the right track.

With mutating cypher queries it is possible to create multiple nodes and relationships in one call. I want to create a query similar to the movie example data that comes with neo4j so that it creates multiple nodes and relationships in one post to the REST API.

Is it possible to write a query like this using neo4jclinet?

I've had a look at the documentation below but I couldn't see an example of the type of query I was after. Im quite new to this so perhaps I missed it.

https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples

Answer (score 1):

Usually there are two ways of doing this. First is to use batch with multiple queries, which [isn't supported by the neo4jclient](http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/issue/5/batch-support#comment-6611403). Looking at the source code shows that there is some kind of batch support (like the `GraphClient.ExecuteBatch` method), but those are private.

The second is to build a Cypher query by adding each node as a parameter, which should result in request as described [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-cypher.html#rest-api-create-multiple-nodes-with-properties). The code would look like this:

```
var queryBuilder = client.Cypher.
    Create ("(movie:Movide {newMovie})");

foreach (Movie movie in movies) {
    queryBuilder = queryBuilder.WithParam ("newMovie", movie);
}

queryBuilder.ExecuteWithoutResults ()
```

This however throws an ArgumentException: "A parameter with the given key is already defined in the query." if there is more then one element on the list.

So you are probably stuck with one of those nasty workarounds:

1. building a query with multiple (indexed) parameters
2. executing one query for one node
3. a [manual query](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher#manual-queries-highly-discouraged), which is discouraged.

This seems to me like an issue worth reporting to Readify.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although this adds multiple nodes it doesn't add the relationships at the same time. I have been looking in to chaining Create to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, chaining Create methods is the first workaround I've mentioned - you still have to take care of naming (indexing) nodes/relationships manually. This is actually what Neo4j `dump` command does. Check out [the output here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/shell-commands.html#_example_dump_scripts). See how cleverly the nodes and relationships are indexed?

Comment: This is still a nasty workaround though. The "right" ways are the ones I've described. But the fact remains that they are not achievable in current version of Neo4jClient.